# Posting more than one answer

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I did a fruitless search here, to see if this has already been asked:  Can a person post more than one answer to the same question?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly possible technically. Whether you want to depends; if the answers are distinct then that's a good idea so that they can be evaluated separately. If they are close, then you may want to put it all into one answer. (If this hasn't been answered already, then I'll convert this to a real answer).

Comment: Well, if the second answer comes to me a while after the first one, I can't consolidate them (edit function only works for a few minutes).

Comment: Something must be wrong then. I'm sure the author of a question or answer can edit all their own stuff they want.

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=more+%22than+one+answer%22 and https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/word-request-answers-one-answer-per-word and https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/should-we-encourage-posting-distinct-answers-separately-particularly-for-sing

Comment: "edit function only works for a few minutes" is true for comments only. There's no time limit on editing a question or answer, whether it's your own or someone else's.

Comment: Chappo's right that only comment has a time limit for editing. That said, from your comment, I have a suspicion you're using comments for answering the question. [Please, don't](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Post your answers on the answer box instead.